# Jquery Mobile + PHP user information

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app that displays a "students" classes. For example, a list is generated on a jQm page ("entity_list") which when clicked will take them to another section on the same page where it will pull a list of information regarding that list. This is done via an id embedded in the url like so:

```
<a href="#entity" data-identity="'.$class['id'].'">'.$class['title'].'</a>
```

When clicked this code is used to extract that information:

```
$("a[href=#entity]").live("click", 
    function(e) {
        navIdentity = $(this).data("identity");
        $.post("entity.php", { entity_id: navIdentity} );
        $("#entity").page();                     
    }
);
```

The problem I am facing is that I can't then extract that id to then load more via php.

Does ANYONE know if theres a better way or how to fix this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does the click event fire? Try adding an `alert('cannons are go');` inside the function above `navIdentity = [...]`. I don't know about .live(), but i usually have to do it like this `.unbind('click').bind('click', function() { })` to overrule JQM standard click handler.

Comment: It works, I've even checked with firebug everything sends...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
navIdentity = $(this).attr("data-identity");
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an issue with the selector. Yours is

```
$("a[href=#entity]")
```

I assume you need to add quotes, like this

```
$("a[href='#entity']")
```

See the jQuery API at http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/